# Group by column and select all fields in rows with multiple minimum values

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, min

I need to select all the fields in a row that are grouped by a certain field and contain the minimum of another field (points), using another field to break ties (id).

Example of data:

| id | game | points | hash |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | x | 5 | ax8 |
| 1 | z | 4 | bc4 |
| 2 | y | 2 | df8 |
| 2 | x | 1 | fd8 |
| 3 | x | 2 | fda0 |
| 3 | y | 2 | fzlf |
| 3 | z | 2 | z89w |

Desired Result:

| id | game | point | hash |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | x | 1 | fd8 |
| 2 | y | 2 | df8 |
| 3 | z | 2 | z89w |

So I'd like to return the row of the minimum amount of points scored in each game and the id that scored it. Notice that if there is a tie, like in game y where id 3 and 2 both scored 2 points, i'd like the row with id 2. In the actual table there are more fields with relevant data.

Current Solution:

```
SELECT g1.*
FROM games g1
  INNER JOIN
  (
    SELECT game, MIN(Point) MinPoint
    FROM games g2
    GROUP BY game
  ) g2
  ON g1.game = g2.game AND g1.point = g2.MinPoint
```

However, I get duplicate rows where two ids scored the same minimum on a game.

Comment: You need to repeat this structure in another level to select the row with minimum ID grouped by game and points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rank your rows with `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
select id, game, points
from
(
  select
    g.*,
    row_number() over (partition by game
                       order by points, id) as rn
  from games g
) ranked
where rn = 1
order by game;
```

This requires MySQL 8.

Another solution: select all rows for which not exists a better row.

```
select *
from games g
where not exist
(
  select null
  from games g2
  where g2.game = g.game
  and
  (
    g2.points < g.points
    or
    (g2.points = g.points and g2.id < g.id)
  )
)
order by game;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have also to group at the top query because a join connects all datasets.

Comment: I can't do a top level group because I need to select fields which are neither grouped nor aggregated